grid search with multiple outputs
I have a CNN model that has to predict two outputs:

regression (bounding box coords)
classification (class of the images with are one-hot vector of len3)

how can i fit the grid search? if i pass as y a dictionary i will get mismatch error because it sees the len of the dictionary as shape
what wrapper to use?
I tried to use KerasClassifier and KerasRegresso but neither of the two works since the outputs are one regression and one classification
I tried to combine the output but it does not work since the model has 2
i tried to use the dictionary and the list for the fit method for grid search
